# Show that $\sin^7 x + \cos^7 x < 1$ if $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could anybody help me solve this Problem? I don't quite get it.

This is what I got.

$\sin^7x+\cos^7x<1$

$0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$

$0<\cos x$

$1>\sin x$

What else?

Comment: If we were given $\sin^7 x + \cos^7 x \le 1$, then this would hold for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Just saying.

Comment: In the domain specified, $\sin x \in (0,1)$ so for $k>0, k\sin x <k$. In particular $\sin^7 x < \sin^6 x < \sin^5 x < \sin^4 x < \sin^3 x < \sin^2 x$.

Answer (score 14):

**hint**: $\sin^7 x < \sin^2 x$ and $\cos^7 x < \cos^2 x$

Comment: That is a very, very quick and elegant solution! I was thinking using derivatives to prove that there is no maximum between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I hope you liked it....

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it!

Comment: Is that seriously it?

Comment: @Barney: It's easy to overthink these things. :-/

Answer (score 5):

Just for the beauty of it, here's $  y = \sin^n x +\cos^n x$ over $[0,2\pi]$ for $n=1..7$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the Pythagorean theorem on the unit circle, we can easily figure out the identity of $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$. We also know that if $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, then $0 < \sin x < 1$ and $0 < \cos x < 1$. We know that if $0<\alpha<1$ and $n>1$ are true, then $\alpha ^n < 1$. If $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, then $\boxed{\sin^7 x + \cos^7 x < 1}$